# How to modify the DOM of a tab created through a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to create a new tab and modify the DOM inside a Chrome Extension's background.js with manifest V3:

```
  chrome.tabs.create({ url : 'http://example.com'},function(newTab) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "Example.com website content modified in tab "+ newTab.id + "!";
  }
```

But why is this not doing anything, and how to fix this?

This below also didn't work:

```
  chrome.tabs.create({ url : 'http://example.com'},function(newTab) {
    function myScript(){
            document.body.innerHTML = "Example.com website content modified in tab "+ newTab.id + "!";
    }

    chrome.scripting.executeScript( {
                    target: {tabId: newTab.id},
                    function: myScript,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

background.js doesn't have access to the dom of a page, you'll have to run content script and use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) to communicate between background and content scripts.

Comment: How would you use messaging? Can do an `eval()` for everything that's passed from background.js to content-script.js?

Comment: That would be a one way to do it, very inadvisable though. A better solution is to move whatever dom manipulation code you planned using in background.js into the content script and background would simply send commands to content script.